# JPA: recursice relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Here my tables:

[image]

Currently I'm modeling my entities like this:

````java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "GITTBUSUARIS")
public class Usuari {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USUARIS_ID")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "USUARIS_CODI")
    private String codi;

    @Column(name = "USUARIS_NOM")
    private String nom;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id.usuari", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<PermisUsuari> permisos;
    
}

As you can see, `permisos` is a `OneToMany` to `PermisUsuari`.

```lang-java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "GITTBUSUARISPERMISOS")
public class PermisUsuari {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private PermisUsuariId id;
    
}
````

And `PermisUsauriId` is:

```
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class PermisUsuariId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USUARISPERMISOS_USUARIID", nullable = false)
    private Usuari usuari;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USUARISPERMISOS_ROLID", nullable = false)
    private Rol rol;

}
```

When I'm getting any `Usuari`, I'm getting it inside their `PermisUsuari` and at the same time it's getting its `Usuari` and so on...

Something like this:

```json
{
   "id":2,
   "codi":"11111111A",
   "nom":"Usuari A",
   "permisos":[
      {
         "id":{
            "usuari":{
               "id":2,
               "codi":"11111111A",
               "nom":"Usuari A",
               "permisos":[
                  {
                     "id":{
                        "usuari":{
                           "id":2,
                           "codi":"11111111A",
                           "nom":"Usuari A",
                           "permisos":[
                              {
                                 "id":{
                                    "usuari":{
                                       "id":2,
                                       "codi":"11111111A",
                                       "nom":"Usuari A",
                                       "permisos":[
                                          {
                                             "id":{
                                                "usuari":{
                                                   "id":2,
                                                   "codi":"11111111A",
                                                   "nom":"Usuari A",
                                                   "permisos":[
                                                      {
                                                         "id":{
                                                            "usuari":{
                                                               "id":2,
                                                               "codi":"11111111A",
                                                               "nom":"Usuari A",
                                                               "permisos":
```

Any ideas about how to solve this model.

Comment: It's always the same. Either let your JSON library know how to handle such object graphs by using e.g. `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` or just use DTOs to model exactly the representation you want to expose without any cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Your entities model is so strange...
Class PermisUsauriId inside the class PermisUsuari,which also inside the Class Usuari , it just like circle and never stop.
I think JPA cannot help with this, try to rebuild a better database relationship.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).